# emu8086 input value to be used in calculation, after conversion value still 0

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am trying to get this code to work, however I keep experiencing problems in the conversion, I tried a bunch of examples that were answers to similar questions, but none of them work, but from it I sort of patched my own version of the code, I think, however it still doesn't work.

```
org  100h

jmp calc


m1 db 0dh, 0ah, "Input width. $"
m2 db 0dh, 0ah, "Input perimeter. $"
m3 db 0dh, 0ah, "width= $"
m4 db 0dh, 0ah, "height= $"                     
width dw 8,0, 8 dup(0)
height dw 8,0, 8 dup(0) 

w dw 0
h dw 0


 calc: 
    mov dx, offset m1
    mov ah, 9                ;output message
    int 21h  

    mov dx, offset width
    mov ah, 0ah            ;read input for width
    int 21h
    mov si, offset width+2 

    xor bx, bx
    .next_digit1:
    xor ax, ax
    mov al, byte ptr [si]
    inc si
    cmp al, '0'
    jb .done1
    cmp al, '9'
    ja .done1
    sub al, '0'
    imul bx, 10               ;convert width string into a number
    add bx, ax
    jmp .next_digit1
    .done1:
    mov ax, bx
    mov w, ax


    mov dx, offset m3
    mov ah, 9                ;output message
    int 21h 
    mov ah, 2         ;output the result
    int 21h   

    mov ah, 0ah            ;read input for width
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset m2
    mov ah, 9                ;output message
    int 21h  

    mov dx, offset height
    mov ah, 0ah            ;read input for width
    int 21h
    mov si, offset height+2 

    xor bx, bx
    .next_digit2:
    xor ax, ax
    mov al, byte ptr [si]
    inc si
    cmp al, '0'
    jb .done2
    cmp cx, '9'
    ja .done2
    sub al, '0'
    imul bx, 10               ;convert width string into a number
    add bx, ax
    loop .next_digit2
    .done2:
    shr ax, 2
    sub ax, w
    mov h, ax


    mov dx, offset m4
    mov ah, 9                ;output message
    int 21h 
    mov ah, 2         ;output the result
    int 21h
```

I have two problems with this.

1. I'm aparently doing something wrong with the division for the perimeter, as it gives this error:

   divide error - overflow.
   to manually process this error,
   change address of INT 0 in interrupt vector table.
2. even though it looks like it should work now, after all of the processing, w and h seem to still equal 0, even though they should equal the values a user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Lemme take a whack at this... Untested!

```
org  100h

jmp calc


m1 db 0dh, 0ah, "Input width. $"
m2 db 0dh, 0ah, "Input perimeter. $"
m3 db 0dh, 0ah, "width= $"
m4 db 0dh, 0ah, "height= $"                     
width dw 8,0, 8 dup(0)
height dw 8,0, 8 dup(0) 

w dw 0
h dw 0


calc: 
mov dx, offset m1
mov ah, 9                ;output message
int 21h  

mov dx, offset width
mov ah, 0ah            ;read input for width
int 21h
mov si, offset width+2 

xor bx, bx
.next_digit1:
xor ax, ax
mov al, byte ptr [si]
inc si
cmp al, '0'
jb .done1
cmp al, '9'
ja .done1
sub al, '0'
imul bx, 10               ;convert width string into a number
add bx, ax
jmp .next_digit1
.done1:
mov ax, bx
mov w, ax


mov dx, offset m3
mov ah, 9                ;output message
int 21h 
; I think you're good to here    

; this is meaningless - what's in dl?
mov ah, 2         ;output the result
int 21h   

; better load dx here, eh?
mov ah, 0ah            ;read input for width
int 21h
; in fact, don't do it here    

mov dx, offset m2
mov ah, 9                ;output message
int 21h  

mov dx, offset height
mov ah, 0ah            ;read input for width
; comment is wrong - no matter
int 21h
mov si, offset height+2 

xor bx, bx
.next_digit2:
xor ax, ax
mov al, byte ptr [si]
inc si
cmp al, '0'
jb .done2
cmp cx, '9'
ja .done2
sub al, '0'
imul bx, 10               ;convert width string into a number
add bx, ax
loop .next_digit2
.done2:
shr ax, 2
sub ax, w
mov h, ax


mov dx, offset m4
mov ah, 9                ;output message
int 21h 

; again, not what you want
mov ah, 2         ;output the result
int 21h
```

I think you've got the "convert string to number" part pretty much right. Now, to output the result, you've got to "convert number to string". You'll probably want to declare a buffer for the string, although it is possible to print it one character at a time. We want to divide the number repeatedly by ten - remembering that `div` uses `dx:ax`. After the `div`, the quotient is in `ax` and the remainder is in `dx`. It is the remainder(s) we're interested in. Unfortunately, we get the remainders "rightmost first" and we want to print 'em "leftmost first". There are several ways to deal with this. The easiest is probably to start at the "end" (the rightmost end) of the buffer and work "backwards". You probably want to pre-fill the buffer with '$'s so you can print it with `int 21h/9`. A 16-bit number could use up to five digits - you want an extra '$'. Starting just before the last '$', as you get a remainder (it'll be between 0 and 9, so just in `dl`) add '0' (48 or 30h) to it, and place it in the buffer. If the quotient is zero, we're done. If not, decrement(!) the index into the buffer and do it again. When you're done, you (probably) won't be at the beginning of the buffer, so transfer your index into the buffer into dx to print it.

An alternative to this is to `push` each remainder onto the stack - count it - and `pop` them off in the correct order to print 'em one at a time. Add '0' before or after. I use to like `int 29h` for this - prints `al` with no side effects, but I'm not sure we're "supposed" to use it. Documented as "for internal use", I understand, but it works great. :)

Unless I'm mistaken, emu8086 includes a debugger, which should be a great help! Ralf Brown's Interrupt List will also help you. The online versions are good, but if you download the whole mess and "install" it, there are "bonus features" (ports.lst. memory.lst, etc.). If you're doing DOS (a waste of time, arguably), Ralf is your best friend! Randy Hyde's old 16-bit "Art of Assembly" is also good. The 32-bit version uses HLA syntax, which is "completely different". The 16-bit version should be "pretty close" to emu8086 syntax, I think.

Courage!

Answer (score 0):

> divide error - overflow. to manually process this error, change address of INT 0 in interrupt vector table.

That indicates a division by zero. You should debug your code and check what values are actually being processed.

Also:

```
mov ax, bx
mov bx, 2
div bx
```

Note that `div` when provided a 16-bit divisor [uses the pair `DX:AX` as dividend](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic). You seem to divide the value of `AX` only, but don't initialize `DX` to zero anywhere. Also not it's much easier (and also more efficient) to use shift right when dividing by 2 (or any power of 2):

```
shr ax, 2   // performs a bitwise shift right, effectively dividing AX by two
```

> even though it looks like it should work now, after all of the processing, w and h seem to still equal 0, even though they should equal the values a user inputs.

Please check the documentation of [function 0Ah of interrupt 21h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a), because it requires buffer to be in a specific format:

- first byte holds the capacity of the buffer
- second byte holds amount of used space: you should initialize it to zero

So if you have an 8-byte buffer (for 8 characters), then the declaration should look like this:

```
# first byte = capacity of 8 characters; 
# second byte = zero to indicate the buffer is initially empty; this will receive the actual size of input read
# remaining eight bytes = the actual buffer, initialized to binary zeros (could be dup(?) as well)
buffer  db 8, 0, 8 dup(0)
```

Comment: I did the division fix, however I really don't understand the buffer format. am i supposed to change the numbers in width dw 4,?, 4 dup('?') and the height one, or am i completely off? I'm sorry if it's a obvious question, I am self-teaching this, and I usually learn by disecting small built programs until i get better at it.

Comment: You should better get some assembbly intro book. You need to learn how to *think* in assembly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax of your assembler, but I don't think `inc width` (and/or `inc height`) does what you want. The input text from `int 21h/0Ah` starts at `offset width + 2` (etc.). Also, the input will include the CR (13 or 0Dh)  - so add 1 to the number of characters you need. I'd `mov si, offset width + 2` and work with that register, getting the character from that, and incrementing it for each loop. Regret that I can't test that for ya, but you're on the right track. Keep at it and you'll be thinking in assembly. Heck, you'll be dreaming in assembly!

Comment: I updated the code with the suggestions, it didn't seem to help though.

Comment: Frank is Right. You definitely have to debug your code and inspect values of registers, memory locations etc. and see for yourself how the code behaves.